# Invalid field from Lead using sobject.put in batch apex

Tags: apex, batch, leads, fields

During a batch apex class, we are copying one field value from one field to another field. Using the following code below we got the error message. How can we resolve this issue?

Steps we have tried to resolve issue but that didn't work:

1. Set field level security to edit for all profiles
2. validated api name is correct

Error message:

> Invalid Field New_text__c from Lead

Code

// execute anonymous

```
string fromField = 'Old_text__c';
string toField = 'New_text__c';
string query = 'select id, Old_Text__c, New_Text__c from Lead';
Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(new myBatchClass(fromField, toField, query);
```

// batch class

```
global class myBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

   global final String Query;
   global final String fromFieldValue;
   global final String toFieldValue;

   global SearchAndReplace(String fromField, String toField,String qry){

      Query=qry; fromFieldValue=fromField; toFieldValue=toField;
   }

   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
     for(sobject sObj : scope){
         // this line below is causing the error
         sObj.put(toFieldValue, sObj.get(fromFieldValue)); 
     }
     update scope;
    }

   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
   }
}
```

Comment: Check Field Level Security.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I set the fields to be edit for all profiles. When i click `set field level security` on the field settings page, it has the Visible=true for all profiles. Any other thought?

Comment: Your fromField value is "Old_Text__c" but your select statement uses Old_Id__c.

Comment: @DavidCheng sorry that was a typo. It should say `Old_Text__c` for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve my issue, I had to navigate to the class that was calling the `Database.executeBatch(new myBatchClass());` and remove `with sharing` on the class